# WCF REST Invoke with POST throws Error

Tags: wcf, rest

I have my interface defined as

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PostUserData", BodyStyle = 
            WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
string GetWine2(string wineID);
```

and service behaviour as

```
public string GetWine2(string wineID)
{
    return "I love this type of : " + wineID;
}
```

when i use the wfetch tool to post the data i consistently get a 405 error from IIS. This lead me to think it is some problem on IIS.
I have tried making a POST call from a custom code and there too i get the same error.
I read on this forum where people had problems because of WebDav, but i dont think i have it installed, would be great if some one can point to me if this is installed, i have no idea what is WebDav.
What could be the other reason on IIS 7.5 to block post calls?

I placed a dummy ASPX page and that serves out fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method should be "POST" ...Change webinvoke like this

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
```

or

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetWine2/{wineID}" BodyStyle = 
        WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```

or

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetWine2/{wineID}") ]
```

What is the URL are you using to invoke this method?

Comment: I am using WFetch, and the url i am using is http://localhost/syncservice/SyncService.svc/GetWine2 and in the Advanced request section i put the "Add Body" Section as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
wineID=11 \r\n

Comment: If my input parameter to the function is of type int then the above UriTemplate wouldnt work. Can you please tell me how would i make it work for non string types as well.

Comment: if u need to pass non string parameters then u can go with json object ..!!

Comment: hi parthi, i am voting your answer as successful, i just wanted to know if i have to pass the message as bare from client without doing json or xml is it possible, how would i do that?